# Query regarding acceptance test maven module

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-test

I've the following structure for my maven multi-module project:

```
parent

|-- main-app

|-- app-dao

|-- acceptance-test
```

The pom.xml of acceptance-test module contains a maven dependency on main-app module.

The structure of the acceptance-test module looks like this:

```
acceptance-test

|--src/test/java
|--src/test/resources
```

The `src/test/java` contains some test files which are dependent on some of the classes belonging to main-app module.

When I run the acceptance test directly from my Intellij IDE, there is no compilation error and the Acceptance test works fine.

But as soon as I try to execute the acceptance-test module using `mvn clean install` command, it fails with Compilation Error.
"`Package abc.xyz doesn't exist`"

Please help.

Comment: Is there a good reason to have a separate module which contains those kind of test? What is special about those acceptance tests? Can you make a real example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified that explicitly, but according to the question's tags, I can assume that `main-app` is a spring boot application.
In this case, it is impossible to make a dependency on that jar (in this case on the `main-app` module) because Spring Boot application is not a jar. You can open it with WinRar/WinZip or any Linux utility and see that it doesn't follow the regular "jar" conventions, namely it includes a `BOOT-INF/lib` folder with all the dependencies on its own.

So, in terms of a solution, I suggest slightly refactor the application to use the following structure:

```java
parent

|-- main-app-boot // this is a spring boot wrapper, no actual code is here

|-- app-services  // all the business logic (services, other beans) are here, but no maven spring boot plugin in pom, so its a regular module

|-- app-dao

|-- acceptance-test // make a dependency on app-services here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. Your suggestion works like a charm.. The main-app-boot was indeed a spring boot fat executable jar and I had to go ahead and make it as a normal jar and create a separate wrapper module.